# Updating text in a tkinter label from motion bind event

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm able to move data from one class frame to another, unfortunately, I can't update the text in the new frame.   I can only pack the new data below the original pack

```
class LabelApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, xy_motion=[-1,-1]):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master )
        self.pack()
        print('LapApp: ' + str(xy_motion[0]))
        self.master = master
        self.xy_motion=xy_motion
        self.xlabel = tk.Label(text=self.xy_motion[0])
        self.xlabel.pack()


    def update_label(self, xy_motion ):
        self.xlabel.config(text=xy_motion[0])
```

the print statement above shows correct data

code that is passing over data

```
class VideoDisplayApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.master = master
        self.image_label = tk.Label(master=self.master)  # label for the vide.
..
.
.

def motion(self, event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    self.xy_motion = [x,y]
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))
    self.motion=tk.Frame(self.master)
    self.app = LabelApp(self.motion, self.xy_motion )
```

Main window

```
class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(padx=15, pady=15)
        self.master.title("Mob")
        self.master.resizable(False, False)
        self.master.tk_setPalette(background='#e6e6e6')

        frame_video = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_video.grid(row=0, column=0)
        # frame_video.geometry("200x200")
        VideoDisplayApp(frame_video)
        #
        frame_bottom = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_bottom.grid(row=1, column=0)
        LabelApp(frame_bottom)
        #
        frame_left = tk.Frame(self)
        frame_left.grid(row=0, column=1)
        ClickOnFrame(frame_left)
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new `LabelApp` each time `motion` is called, if you want to _update_ rather than _create_ a label?

Comment: yes, that is my problem,  I'm not sure how to update it directly

Comment: Have you done any research? Methods to update widgets are well documented, and there are _lots_ of questions on stackoverflow related to updating widgets.

Comment: yes, I know most python question probably have already been answered, but I'm missing something.

Comment: It seems like most of the documentation is addressing a single class example

Comment: I don't even understand what you want to do. If you want to update the label's text, well, use `self.image_label['text'] = 'whatever'`? I'm really not sure what the problem is.

Comment: problem is that either I create a new LabelApp which just adds a new text label to the bottom.  Or if make LabelApp a Singolten I lose the reference to the original Label